# Python big list and input to database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I must parse HTML files, which can be up to 500 000 links.
Of which 400 000 will be desired by me.

Should I put all the links that satisfy the condition for the new list and then for the elements of this list and put it into the database.

Or when I find links to satisfy the condition to add it to the database (sqlite) (and commit it).
Is that a large number of commits is not a problem?

I do not want to lose data in case of failure such as power. Thats why i want commit after  insert to the database.

How best to place a large number of items in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider just doing a commit after every 1000 records or so

Answer (score 1):

If these many links are spread across several files, what about a commit after processing each file? Then you as well could remember which files you have processed.

In the case of a single file, record the file offset after each commit for clean continuation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use noSQL database like mongo. With mongo I add 500.000 documents with 6 fields  in each added about 15 seconds (on my old laptop), and about 0.023 sec on not difficult queries.